# Klingon for 'arrow'?

Tags: star-trek, languages, klingon-language

I'm running a Dungeons and Dragons campaign. There are orcs in this campaign. There's going to be a scene with Orcs where they will speak their native language: Giant. I've decided to use Klingon to represent this language, so I don't have to make it all up. I'm not going to have conversations or anything, I'm just going to have a few key phrases ready-translated.

I'm a fan of Star Trek, but not to the point where I'm familiar with the Klingon language.

The word 'arrow' is going to come up a couple times. The Bing translator doesn't have a translation for 'arrow'. Obviously, I could just make something up, but that kind of ruins the fun. I might just use 'torpedo' ('peng'), as that's at least a projectile.

Is there something better? As fond of warfare as klingons are, I'm surprised if there's no word for 'arrow'.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

#### From the [KLV Klingon/Standard Vocabulary](https://sites.google.com/a/klingonword.org/klv/klv-klingon-standard-vocabulary)

Arrow is translated as *puv DuQwI'*

It is literally translated as "flying spike".

Comment: Just out of curiosity, how do you pronounce that?

Comment: Yes, puv DuQwI' is correct. I'm using vegh DuQwI' myself for spear (e.n. penetrating spike / spike that goes through).

Comment: You're on the right track, but **puv DuQwI'** actually means "the stabber flies"; it is a statement, rather than an object. In order to make it "the flying stabber", you'll need to use the relative clause suffix -**bogh**, making it **puvbogh DuQwI'**.

Answer (score 6):

I asked this question of some Klingons (actually, some Klingon speakers who are members of the Klingon Language Institute). The top suggestion was **naQjejHom**, using the word for spear (**naQjej**) with the diminutive suffix (**-Hom**). A second suggestion was to use **tlhevjaQ** (a type of Klingon spear-like weapon which is thrown with the aid of a launcher called a **chetvI'**). As for bow, either **chetvI'** (or **naQjejHom chetvI'** or **tlhevjaQ chetvI'** to be more specific) or **moy'bI'** (which means "slingshot") might work.

Comment: It should be noted that the description of a **chetvI'** suggests that it is similar to an [atlatl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spear-thrower). Therefore, I think a **chetvI'** and a **tlhevjaQ** could fill the same purpose as a bow and arrow in a story, but I think their physical properties are quite different. Therefore, for the bow in particular, I think **moy'bI'** is a closer match, since it uses a similar firing mechanism.

Comment: +1, Nice research. This is also pretty close to loghaD's suggestion of "small spear". I'm going to leave Thaddeus's answer as the accepted one, as we already played this session and I already used "puv DuQqwl'".

Answer (score 4):

There is no canonical Klingon word for "arrow". The closest thing I can think of is a spear, or **naQjej** (which essentially means "sharp staff"). This includes spears that are thrown by hand and ones that are hurled using specialized tools.

An arrow is essentially a small spear, so in lieu of a canonical expression, I would call it a **naQjejHom** ("lesser spear") or **naQjej mach** ("small spear").

Comment: "Flying spike" seems like it works better than "small spear". There aren't too many other things on the battlefield that might be called flying spikes. There is a very specific group of things I would think of before arrows when referring to small spears: small spears.

Comment: @DCShannon It may be largely a difference in taste, and as dungeon master I think you should go with whatever suits you best. However, as a Klingon-speaker, the phrase puvbogh DuQwI' doesn't really conjure the image of an arrow to me.

The word **DuQwI'** has previously only been used to describe spikes attached to something else: On a glove, on a **Daqtagh** knife, and on a mace.

It could be that the word is broader than that, since it just means "stabber", but then then it could potentially describe any piercing weapon, including a spear.